# eloquent select all table with relationship many to many

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables (workflow, user, workflow_user) and I would like to select the view column of the workflow_user table.

```
class Workflow extends Model
{

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'workflow_user');
    }
}
```

```
class User extends Model
{

    public function works()
    {
        //return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
        return $this->belongsToMany(Workflow1::class,'workflow_user');
    }
}
```

workflow_user table

```
class WorkflowUser extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'workflow_user';
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'workflow1_id','user_id','view'
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

To get the data from the workflow_user table I do this

`$workflow = User::find($idconnect)->works()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(10);`

When I make this request it does not give me the data of the workflow_user(workflow1_id,user_id,view) table.

Comment: What is your problem ? What is it giving you ? Also, remember to follow Laravel naming standard, you table should have been called `user_workflow`, and what is `Workflow1` model ? Really strange name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a model for the pivot table, you should have it extend the `Pivot` class and use it in the relationship's definition.

Also, you need to manually include the fields that are not the foreign ids in the query result.

```php
class Workflow extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'workflow_user', 'workflow_id', 'user_id')
                    ->using(WorkflowUser::class)
                    ->withPivot(['id', 'view']);
    }
}
```

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function works()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Workflow::class, 'workflow_user', 'user_id', 'workflow_id')
                    ->using(WorkflowUser::class)
                    ->withPivot(['id', 'view']);
    }
}
```

workflow_user table

```php
class WorkflowUser extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'workflow_user';    
    protected $fillable = ['workflow_id', 'user_id', 'view'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $incrementing = true;
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

```php
$workflow = User::findOrFail($idconnect)
                ->works()
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->paginate(10);
```